# Recursive function to know if a number is divisible by 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, recursion, division

I need to create a recursive function which return me true if the input number it's divisible by 3. I know that it's more simple without recursion, but I need to create a function of this type.

I've created a function, but i want to know if it's possible to create a better one, 'cause whit a big 'num', the function doesn't work. I think that I should use this fact: a natural number is divisible by 3 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3.

This is my code:

```
def divThree(num):
    if num==3:
        return true
    else:
        divThree(num-3)
```

EDIT: I created a better function, but i don't understand why doesn't return me true if the number is divisible by three. Instead, if it isn't, goes on maximum recursion error.

```
def recursiveThree(num):
  if num==3 or num==6 or num==9:
    return true
  else:
    sum=0
    sNum=str(num)
    for i in range(0,len(sNum)):
      sum=sum+int(sNum[i])
    recursiveThree(sum)
```

Comment: `return num % 3 != 0`

Comment: you didn't specify error or how big number you have entered but assuming number is positive integer with power of 15 or above I think you may get maximum recursion depth limit reach error. And that is we want to solve so we optimize our code accordingly.

Comment: _Why_ does your function need to be recursive? It's a requirement that rules out the obvious and sensible solutions, and leaves only peculiar, broken, inefficient and unnatural solutions (especially since Python doesn't do tail recursion, and places a fairly low limit on recursion level). If this is an assignment, it's a poor one.

Comment: It's an university excercise, so i MUST use recursion, also if it's better, and more simple using a for cicle

Comment: @user8024584: Okay, but it's still an odd requirement without more details. For example: `def divisible_by_three(n): return n % 3 == 0 if random.random() < 0.1 else divisible_by_three(n)` satisfies the requirement of using recursion, but is almost certainly not what your instructor is looking for.

Comment: He wants a recursive function, which returns true if the input number is divisible by three.

We must use this math fact: "a natural number is divisible by 3 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3".

So, i think that i can't use the operator "/" and check if the division rest is 0..

I know that it's an useless function if created in this way, but it's an excercise to make us understand recursion!

Comment: Ah, it's a _requirement_ from the instructor that you use the math fact? That does add a little bit more helpful context.

Comment: Yes, because using division operator it's too simple (in his opinion)

Comment: I hate that kind of instructor. Exercises should be designed so that each exercise has a solution within its restrictions that would be a good solution with the restrictions gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The most straightforward solution is to use modulo 3 to check for
  divisibility, but that's not going to be recursive.
- An alternate solution is to recursively keep dividing by 3 until you get down to 1, but that will stack overflow for large values.
- A third solution, which lends itself to recursion, is to leverage the property that if the sum of the digits of a number is divisible by 3, then the number is divisible by 3.

Here's an implementation of the third option that avoids modulo arithmetic and copes with very large numbers:

```
def divThree(num):
    if num < 10:
        return (num in [3, 6, 9])
    else:
        return divThree(sum([int(digit) for digit in str(num)]))
```

You can add 0 to the list in the first `return` if you want to consider it divisible by 3 as well.

If you want to accommodate both positive and negative values, prepend:

```
if num < 0:
    return divThree(-num)
```

as the first check to be performed.

Comment: Nice answer, given the peculiar requirements. It may be worth noting that even `divThree` is _much_ more inefficient for really large numbers (e.g., `10**10**6`) than the `% 3` check, since the int -> str conversion takes time quadratic in the number of digits. (For `10**10**6`, I get a timing of 13.7 seconds for `divThree` versus 0.00143 seconds for a simple `%3`-based function. I haven't dared try `divThree` with an input of `10**10**7`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the number has zero remainder when using 3 as the divisor.

Use the `%` operator to check for a remainder. So if you want to see if something is evenly divisible by 3 then use `num % 3 == 0` If the remainder is zero then the number is divisible by 3.

This returns true:

```
print (6 % 3 == 0)
returns True
```

This returns False:

```
print (5 % 3 == 0)
returns False
```

Here is a simple function to check True of False:

```
def divThree(numb):
    return numb % 3 == 0

print (divThree(99))
```

Edit:

I am not sure how big a number you are trying to check but I tested this function with what I think is a big number and it worked. I could be just not understanding what it is you need thought.

```
def divThree(numb):
    return numb % 3 == 0

print (divThree(4325609549876542987503216540321540104986213754901245217346214390735402153407213540213457183254098263487053214132754073254921534987053245321454))

Returned True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find out what it would take for the number to become divisible by 3 using the modulo and then subtracting that to num

```
 def divThree(num):
      if num % 3 == 0:
        return True
      a = num % 3
      return divThree(num-a)
```

Comment: What is the variable "n" in line 2?

Comment: Should have been variable num not n

Comment: This will always return True. Take num = 11, a = 2, num - a = 9.

Answer (score 0):

You enlarge recursively the factor to subtract:

```
def divisible_by_tree(num, factor=3):
    if factor < num:
        num = divi(num, factor * 2)
    if num >= factor:
        num -= factor
    if factor > 3:
       return num
    return num == 0
```

Comment: `if factor > 3`, really?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an obscure method, and there are several better answers, but implementing a theorem of congruences, you could say:

```
from random import randint # For test trials

def isDivisByThree(n):
    sN = str(n)
    if(len(sN) == 1):
        bIsProductOfThree=True if(n==3 or n==6 or n==9) else False
        return bIsProductOfThree
    else:
        sumOfDigits = 0
        for x in sN:
            sumOfDigits += int(x)
        # end for
        return isDivisByThree(sumOfDigits)
    # end if
# end isDivisByThree(...)

def main():
    for testTrialCount in range(1, 35+1):
        testSubject = randint(1, 2147483647)
        result = isDivisByThree(testSubject)
        if(result):
            print("Test Trial #" + str(testTrialCount) + ": " + str(testSubject) + " is divisble by 3!")
        else:
            print("Test Trial #" + str(testTrialCount) + ": " + str(testSubject) + " is NOT divisble by 3.")
        # end if
    # end for
# end main()

main()
```

This works because of a theorem related to the application of congruences which states: if *`d|(b-1)`* then *`n = (a_k * ... * a_1 * a_0)`* is divisible by *d* if and only if the sum of digits *`a_k + ... + a_1 + a_0`* is divisible by *d*. (*Where `d` is the divisor (3 for this example) and `b` is the base in which the number is expressed (10 for this example).*)

Example output for the first 10 trials:

```
Test Trial #1: 458327921 is NOT divisble by 3.
Test Trial #2: 23787660 is divisble by 3!
Test Trial #3: 820562190 is divisble by 3!
Test Trial #4: 1466915534 is NOT divisble by 3.
Test Trial #5: 1395854683 is NOT divisble by 3.
Test Trial #6: 1844052852 is divisble by 3!
Test Trial #7: 261731131 is NOT divisble by 3.
Test Trial #8: 624183104 is NOT divisble by 3.
Test Trial #9: 788686237 is NOT divisble by 3.
Test Trial #10: 1075010016 is divisble by 3!
...
```

---

**Edit**:

Ah, I see pjs beat me to this with a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

In C (easy to translate)

```
bool divisible_by_three (int x) {
    if (x < 0) return divisible_by_three (-x);
    else if (x >= 3) return divisible_by_three (x % 3);
    else return (x == 0);
}
```

Yes, it's recursive. Exercise for your instructor: Find the bug.